# How to decide PCB specification

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, pcb-fabrication

Everything is in the title. Let's say I design a PCB layout. It has 4 layers. How do I decide:

1. The material to use for the PCB (difference between FR TG 130, FR TG170, Aluminium, or other materials)
2. PCB Thickness (I suppose this is partially dictated by the stack and by requirement of potential impedance matching, but does anybody can explain with an example?)
3. Surface finishing (when to use HASL vs ENIG, vs OSP vs Gold or vs Immersion tin)
4. Copper weight (1,2,3,4 oz)

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: In your situation I would recommend to go with manufacturer's defaults.

Comment: This is pretty broad, but could benefit from a wiki-style answer.

Comment: Titles are not for content.

Comment: Given the fact that the answer is "Use the cheapest that meets your needs", do we get to close questions about the best LED/Boost converter/Soldering iron as dupes of this one?

Answer (score 11):

> The material to use for the PCB (difference between FR TG 130, FR TG170, Aluminium, or other mateials)

Use the lowest cost material that meets your needs. If you don't have special needs, this is typically FR4 (there are even lower cost materials for truly mass-market products). Higher Tg might be desirable if you are doing lead-free assembly (unfortunately I can't give specifics here).

> PCB Thickniess

If you don't have a specific reason to do otherwise, use 1.6 mm (63 mil). This will give reasonable mechanical rigidity and compatibility with the maximum number of through-hole parts.

If you have a very high layer count (more than 16 layers, maybe) you might need to go thicker.

If you are trying to fit certain edge-card connectors you might need to go thinner (1 mm is not uncommon).

> Surface finishing (when to use HASL vs ENIG, vs OSP vs Gold or vs Immersion tin)

Use the cheapest finish that meets your needs. Typically this is HASL.

Gold finish may be desirable if you are using edge-card connectors or otherwise using the copper surface as a switch contact, or if you are wirebonding to PCB pads.

> Copper weight (1,2,3,4 oz)

Use the cheapest that meets your needs.

Typically this is 1/2 or 1 oz. 1/2 oz may be preferred on outer layers to allow finer features; after copper plating it will be roughly equivalent to 1 oz unplated copper in current-handling capability.

Thicker copper may be needed if your circuit must handle very high currents.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with The Photon but would like to add two points:

Surface Finishing : Are you selling the boards anywhere RoHS applies? If so, you have to specify RoHS compliant finish, which HASL may not be (it's usually leaded solder).

Copper weight : anything above 1oz may require more heat in your soldering process (especially hand soldering, because copper conducts heat away from the joint area well, and thick copper does so even better). Talk to your assembly line, but 2oz and above are probably only useful for high current applications.

Comment: For RoHS compliance, you can specify "lead-free HASL" instead of just "HASL".